# Switching the GPIO of a Raspberry Pi at a fixed frequency

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi

I have a 208 - 232 Bit long binary signal that I want to send via a GPIO of the raspberry pi.
The delay between the bits needs to be constant.
How can I achieve this ?

The simplest solution that came to my mind was this (pseudocode):

```
send(gpio, message, delay){
  for(int i = 0; i < lenght(message); i++){
    if (message[i] == 1){
      gpio.high()
    }
    else{
      gpio.low()
    }
    sleep(delay)
  }
}
```

But the frequency at which I want to send this message is around 40kHz so the delay between two bits is only 25us.
How can I assure it is exactly&constantly that much delay.

Comment: If this is code running in userspace in Linux, there is no way to guarantee timing. There are things you can do to give you a better chance, but you're at the mercy of the scheduler.

Comment: I mean I could run it in kernel mode, no ? If no, do you know about hardware which can buffer a message and then release it a a fixed frequency ? ...maybe a shift register ?

Comment: 200+ bits is pretty long for using fully-buffered before sending. Doing it in kernel mode would at least make it possible, but things will be tricky to get the timing you want without effectively killing the rest of the OS. There might be some fancy DMA thing you could do. Is there a reason that you're not using a microcontroller to do it?

Comment: The reason that I dont use a microcontroller is that I want to display an animation that is generated with the message data. So I need a video output and don't know how I could achieve this with a uc. ... but wait :) thats a great idea actually because only one member needs to display that; at the display member I only need to receive these messages and send very short requests; for the sender I could in fact use a uc

Answer (score 0):

In userspace there is no way to garantee that anything is happening in "real time".

Because of this I decided using a seperate Microcontroller that is responsible for time critical features that communicates via I2C or UART with the RaspberryPi.

This way the RaspberryPi can do high abstraction level decisions and show animation to a user while being able to send messages over ultrasound.

Another way I came up with is to create a file similar to .wav and then use DMA or other techniques like with audio. But as I haven't tried it I don't know if the Pi is sufficient to do this at higher Samplingrates.